# Import of lettable operators and observable creation methods

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-lettable-operators

I'm upgrading to Angular 5 and RxJS 5.5.2 and trying to import `Observable.of` operator.

Before lettable operators, we did it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Usage
Observable.of(...)
```

But now importing from paths containing `add` is discouraged.

So what is the proper way of importing and using lettable static operators now?

Comment: read the docs? https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operators that have now a lettable version are the instance operators.

Since before **5.5.x** `of` and any other **observable creation methods** can be used as in a static way as follows:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

The [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#usage) from `rxjs` are pretty clear on this topic:

> You pull in any operator you need from one spot, under 'rxjs/operators' (plural!). It's also recommended to pull in the Observable creation methods you need directly as shown below with range:

```
import { range } from 'rxjs/observable/range';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source$ = range(0, 10);

source$.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
  map(x => x + x),
  scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: `now a lettable version are the instance operators` not sure how to use them now. Could you post an example of creating an `Observable` from a constant value of `1`? Also, what if we need to import multiple static operators e.g. `of` and `from` - is there a way to combine the imports in one line?

Comment: updated, and nope, there is no barrel file on rxjs/observable, you need to import one by one