# RxJS lettable operators for Observable.create

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-lettable-operators

Is there a lettable operator for `Observable.create()` imported from `rxjs/Observable`?

I already replaced the `Observable.of()` also imported from `rxjs/Observable` by the lettable operator `of()` imported from `rxjs/observable/of`.

But I could not find a lettable operator for the first issue, anyone who could help?

EDIT: Not a duplicate, this question is about using Observable.create() as a lettable operator, and not about importing and using lettable static operators as Observable.of()

Comment: I don't think there is any. Methods such as `Observable.of()` or `Observable.from()` had to be added by patching the prototype but `Observable.create()` is a static method already https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L58

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import of lettable operators and observable creation methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189540/import-of-lettable-operators-and-observable-creation-methods)

Answer (score 0):

There's no lettable operator for `Observable.create`. It is part of the class definition so it can be used just by importing Observable itself without it creating the problems that lettable operators solved (import fall through, tree shaking and so on).

So either

TypeScript:

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    ...
    Observable.create(...)
```

Or as a *normal* lib

```
    Rx.Observable.create(...)
```

Would do just fine :)

Comment: Just noticed martin had answered this question very similarly quite a while ago. The link he provided is no longer valid, though. Here's the current link to the same place: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L58